# Bash script grep for pattern in variable of text

Tags: regex, string, bash, grep

I have a variable which contains text; I can echo it to stdout so I think the variable is fine. My problem is trying to grep for a pattern in that variable of text. Here is what I am trying:

```
ERR_COUNT=`echo $VAR_WITH_TEXT | grep "ERROR total: (\d+)"`
```

When I echo $ERR_COUNT the variable appears to be empty, so I must be doing something wrong.

How to do this properly? Thanks.

EDIT - Just wanted to mention that testing that pattern on the example text I have in the variable does give me something (I tested with: http://rubular.com)

However the regex could still be wrong.

EDIT2 - Not getting any results yet, so here's the string I'm working with:

`ALERT line125: Alert: Cannot locate any description for 'asdf' in the qwer.xml hierarchy. (due to (?i-xsm:\balert?\b) ALERT in ../hgfd.controls) ALERT line126: Alert: Cannot locate any description for 'zxcv' in the qwer.xml hierarchy. (due to (?i-xsm:\balert?\b) ALERT in ../dfhg.controls) ALERT line127: Alert: Cannot locate any description for 'rtyu' in the qwer.xml hierarchy. (due to (?i-xsm:\balert?\b) ALERT in ../kjgh.controls) [1] 22280 IGNORE total: 0 WARN total: 0 ALERT total: 3 ERROR total: 23 [1] + Done /tool/pandora/bin/gvim -u NONE -U NONE -nRN -c runtime! plugin/**/*.vim -bg ...`

That's the string, so hopefully there should be no ambiguity anymore... I want to extract the number "23" (after "ERROR total: ") into a variable and I'm having a hard time haha.

Cheers

Comment: So are you looking for the following pattern: `ERROR total: ([0-9]*)`?

i.e. would `ERROR total: (42)` be an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: In the text I have patterns like: "..asdfasdfasdf ERROR total: 55 qwerweqrfdsa.." and I want to pin-point that number "55" after I see "ERROR total: "

Comment: are there linebreaks in the input? is the pattern only once occuring or possibly multiple times?

Comment: Yes the input is multiple lines. And the pattern only occurs once in the input.

Comment: @YoungMoney, your input doesn't look like it has multiple lines!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use bash's `=~` operator to extract the value.

```
[[ $VAR_WITH_TEXT =~ ERROR\ total:\ ([0-9]+) ]]
```

Note that you have to escape the spaces, or only only quote
the fixed parts of the regular expression:

```
[[ $VAR_WITH_TEXT =~ "ERROR total: "([0-9]+) ]]
```

since quoting any of the metacharacters causes them to be treated
literally.

You can also save the regex in a variable:

```
regex="ERROR total: ([0-9]+)"
[[ $VAR_WITH_TEXT =~ $regex ]]
```

In any case, once the expression matches, the parenthesized expression
can be found in `BASH_REMATCH` array.

```
ERR_COUNT=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

(The zeroth element contains the entire matched regular expression; the parenthesized subexpressions are found in the remaining elements in the order they appear in the full regex.)

---

If you want to use `grep`, you'll need a version that can accept Perl-style regexes.

```
ERR_COUNT=$( echo "$VAR_WITH_TEXT" | grep -Po "(?<=ERROR total: )\d+" )
```

As long as you need to use Perl-style regexes to enable the look-behind assertion, you can replace `[0-9]` with `\d`.

Comment: +1 ... and make sure you have double quotes around your variable.  `echo "$VAR_WITH_TEXT"`.  Apart from other atrocities, echoing an unquoted string will squash it all on a single line, so `grep` will return the entire string.

Comment: Good point, in general. In this case, though, we're safe; `grep -o` is only going to output the matched text, the number following "ERROR total:". But there's no reason *not* to quote the variable.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I can't get your first solution (with BASH_REMATCH) to work, however I can get the second solution with grep -Po to work if I echo $var without quotes...

Answer (score 3):

Your error is in the pattern: `(\d+)` matches:

- `'('`
- a digit
- `'+'`
- `')'`

According to your comment, what you want is `\(\d\+\)`, which:

- defines a sub-pattern by `\( ... \)`

  - Inside it matches at least one (`\+`) digit (`\d`).

In this case, if you don't need a sub-pattern, you can just drop the `\(` and `\)`.

Note: if your `grep` doesn't understand `\d`, you can replace it by `[0-9]`. Easiest way is to write `grep '\d'` and test it by writing a couple test lines.

Comment: Hi, so I tried changing my original command to egrep. I also tried replacing \d with [0-9], etc. None of it works. I think I'll just post the data I'm working with in the OP since this is getting sorta frustrating..

Comment: @YoungMoney The data you posted doesn't have multiple lines! Are you sure it's correct? Also, try changing the space before the parentheses to `\s*` that matches any whitespace. Could it be that there is a tab or something, and not space?

Answer (score 2):

```
# setting example data
    test="adfa\nfasetrfaqwe\ndsfa ERROR total: 32514235dsfaewrf"
```

**one solution:**

```
echo $(sed -n 's/^.*ERROR total: \([0-9]*\).*$/\1/p' < <(echo $test))
32514235
```

**other solution:**

```
# throw away everything up to "ERROR total: "
test=${test##*ERROR total: } 
# cut from behind assuming number contains no spaces and is
# separated by space
test=${test%% *}
echo $test
32514235
```

Comment: Hey I'll try this out. There's no (parenthesis) around the number though, so if I just remove the ( and the ) from your solution this should be fine? Also I don't really understand your solution - is that still regex?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to get either of your solutions to work. I've posted the actual string I'm working with in the question. Solution 1 has a syntax error about the "<" character, and other solution gave me a different word in the string (not the number). Thanks for your help so far though.

Answer (score 1):

The `\d` is probably only recognized as a digit in perl regex mode, you probably want to use `grep -P`.

If you only want the number you could try:

`ERR_COUNT=$(echo $VAR_WITH_TEXT | perl -pe "s/.*ERROR total: (\d+).*/\1/g")`

or:

`ERR_COUNT=$(echo $VAR_WITH_TEXT | sed -n "s/.*ERROR total: ([0-9]+).*/\1/gp")`

Comment: `\d` isn't part of ERE or BRE. It's a PCRE extension (as well as regex engines based on PCRE).

Comment: So make it `grep -P` or fix the pattern to something compatible with basic regular expressions.  This still has the problem that `grep` will output the entire matching line, which will be the whole string if you don't double-quote it.